# Corded mouse with burst function and switchable scroll wheel

Tags: pc, mice, windows

I am looking for a new mouse (for work and gaming). It should have a burst function (lots of clicks while clicking a button) and a scroll wheel which works similar like the one from the Logitech M500, where I had a button to unlock the scroll wheel, so that I can scroll a long way by just swinging the scrollwheel once.

It is quite hard to look for those specific functions in any stores, so, maybe you know a model which has those functions.

For the rest of the specs, it should be a corded mouse, maybe has some extra buttons (but not too many, like the Razer Naga for instance), should be suitable for big hands. I had the Logitech M500 until now, which I found very ergonomic, if this helps =)

So, the features I want:

- burst function
- unlock scroll wheel
- corded
- not too many buttons

The rest doesn't matter.

I would appreciate some suggestions.